# New PC, Keyboard and OS and I can't do a Screen Image Capture

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I just got a new PC, Windows 7 Ultimate with a fancy MS keyboard:

[image]

I am puzzled why ALT+PRTSCN keyboard combo seems to put nothing on my keyboard. No lights are on the keybd (SCROLL LOCK, SHIFT, etc)-yet, when I paste into Word Pad or Paint or some program that should be able to hande images, no image is on the clipboard.

Any ideas what to try?

Comment: Have you tried just "Print Screen" on it's own to get the entire desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logitech keyboards often have a "F-Lock" key, which gives the F keys(also the prnt scrn etc) a differant meaning, mostly multimedia keys.

Could this be the case? In the screenshot it isn't that clear to see for myself, but I expect something similar too.

So try to find F-Lock/however it's called, and give that a try. If that does not work please tell the exact type of the keyboard, so I can look at the keys better.

Comment: The F-Lock key for the keyboard in the picture is located left of the Microsoft logo.

Comment: Hitting the F-Lock + PrtScrn button seem to do the trick. Funny. I dont think I ever saw a keyboard with F-Lock on it. Ty!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take screenshots with just one click you should try [ScreenHunter Free](http://download.cnet.com/ScreenHunter-Free/3000-2192_4-10063246.html?tag=mncol).  It saves to a customizable .jpg/gif/png file for you with just one click.

Answer (score 0):

This really should just be a comment because you already have an answer, but I don't think the system gives me that option because I'm a new user.

One other cool way to do screenshots in win7 without extra software is by using All Programs --> Accessories --> Snipping Tool.  You can choose the size of the box to copy to clipboard.